# Making list of lines that contain string in other list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a text file, Input.txt
Input.txt looks something like this:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 "D:\path\string" word5
```

Where the words arbitrarily change from one line to the next. I have a list (let's call it List1) with plenty of different strings, and I need to make a new list for every line in Input.txt where the "string" part is the same as any one of the elements in List1.

The closest I've gotten is by doing this:

```
strings = List1
with open("Input.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if any(s in line for s in strings):
          print(line)
```

But this only prints the lines I want (and if I copy what it prints, it isn't properly formatted (as in, it just prints all the lines as one string rather than separating by lines) - and I could format it properly but I want to find the most efficient way of doing this).

In short, what's the most efficient and idiomatic way to make a list (let's say List2) of each line that contains a string from List1, such that if I write List2 to another text file, there will be one element of List2 per line?

Comment: do you want to change 'word1 word2 word3 word4 "D:\path\string" word5'

Comment: to list like that list=[word1,word2,...,..]

Comment: Your question is unclear be more specific with your goal.

Comment: I want to keep the content of each line that appears in List2 the same as they were in List1. I also know how to define lists manually (list=[word1, etc]), but I need to find a way to enter the elements of the list automatically. So to take the example of my code, it would be a list of every "line" as referred to in my fourth line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
strings = []
with open("Input.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print lines
```

if not work Try this

```
strings = []
with open("Input.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split(' ')
    print lines
```

Comment: All this does is make a list of ALL the lines in Input.txt if I'm not mistaken. What I'm looking to do is make a list of the lines in Input.txt that contain a string from a list (that I already have - List1 as it's mentioned in my question).